# R, too much data in data.frame

Tags: r

I have problem with data in R. I'm loading data with:

```
data<-read.csv2("ceny_paliwo.csv", dec = ",")
data
```

an this is giving me:

```
     X  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug Sept  Oct  Nov  Dec
1 2014 5.32 5.34 5.34 5.27 5.29 5.23 5.29 5.22 5.19 5.17 4.98 4.75
2 2015 4.46 4.47 4.62 4.58 4.65 4.71 4.66 4.49 4.30 4.28 4.36 4.21
3 2016 3.87 3.73 3.86 3.90 4.07 4.23 4.17 4.10 4.26 4.35 4.32 4.53
4 2017 4.62 4.58 4.53 4.48 4.36 4.19 4.17 4.31 4.37 4.44 4.59 4.59
```

after this:

```
data2 <- round(unname(unlist(as.data.frame(data))), digits = 2)
data2
```

I'm receiving:

```
 [1] 2014.00 2015.00 2016.00 2017.00    5.32    4.46    3.87    4.62    5.34    4.47    3.73    4.58    5.34
[14]    4.62    3.86    4.53    5.27    4.58    3.90    4.48    5.29    4.65    4.07    4.36    5.23    4.71
[27]    4.23    4.19    5.29    4.66    4.17    4.17    5.22    4.49    4.10    4.31    5.19    4.30    4.26
[40]    4.37    5.17    4.28    4.35    4.44    4.98    4.36    4.32    4.59    4.75    4.21    4.53    4.59
```

What I'm trying to do, is to don't have `2014.00 2015.00 2016.00 2017.00` this data in the first row.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Use `t` to transpose matrices. `t(your_data)`.

Comment: `data2 <- round(unname(unlist(as.data.frame(data[,-1]))), digits = 2)`

Comment: Thank you guys for help, now it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select only data from the second column like here:

```
data2 <- round(unname(unlist(as.data.frame(data[,c(2:ncol(data))]))), digits = 2)
```